# In Google Apps Script MailApp is it possible to pass javascript in the htmlBody?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Not sure if it is possible, but I was playing around trying to pass a simple alert javascript function in the htmlBody. The email arrives with a button, when you click the button, it calls the simple javascript function. This doesn't seem to work and I was wondering if it is simply not permitted by Google?

```
function sendEmail(){

var body = '<html><body><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button><script>function myFunction()    {windows.alert();}</script></body></html>'
MailApp.sendEmail("testemail@hotmail.com","test subject", "",{htmlBody: body});

}
```

Thanks!

Shawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No mail client allows the script HTML tag inside the body of an email message.

Comment: Ok. I had a feeling. BTW thanks for your GAS blog (I thing it is yours)! I used some of your examples in the past.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's my blog.